# How to check if user is logged in and redirect them to the right screen using Jetpack Navigation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

what is the best way to save user logged in state, check if they logged in or not and redirect them to the right screen. I'm not using firebase Auth in this current project please any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's a tutorial section in the Navigation docs that covers exactly this scenario: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Answer (score 1):

the page where we created the user

```
val prefences = activity?.getSharedPreferences("control", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = prefences?.edit()
editor?.putString("usercontrol",value) // After creating the user you give value 1 
editor?.apply()
```

on the login page

```
val shared = getSharedPreferences("kontrol", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val control = shared.getLong("date", 0)
```

I suggest you look at the SharedPreferences structure

Comment: I have a problem using shared preferences, datastore with composables, Home Screen (start destination) user is currently null so it should navigate to the login screen whenever the app gets recreated but the Home Screen shows up again before it navigates to the login screen

Comment: before going to the login screen the main screen appears but does it go by quickly

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: Hi Omer, thanks but I solved it by creating a splash screen composable and wrote the logic there so whenever the app gets recreated the splash screen will show up first because it's the start destination.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. 
can you please support.